# Como posso verificar se a imagem já existe no banco mysql e no diretório?

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá, estou fazendo **crud** e agora me deu dor de cabeça na etapa de imagens. Basicamente eu quero poder cadastrar uma imagem que tenha um nome único no banco e no diretório e que depois se necessário na pagina de update eu possa verificar se o usuário está tentando colocar a mesma imagem que já estava antes no sistema. Gostaria de saber se da forma que estou criando o nome do arquivo eu posso recuperar de alguma forma depois para poder fazer a verificação se já está cadastrado ou não... Abaixo está o código de como eu estou criando o nome da imagem no banco e no diretório, obrigado pela atenção!

```
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo(basename($_FILES["linkimg"]["name"]),PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$imagem = md5(uniqid()) . '-' . time() . '.'.$imageFileType;
$target_file = $target_dir . $imagem;
```

Comment: Remova essa imagem e coloque o código no formato de texto, por favor.

Comment: pronto, só isso ou algo mais ?

Comment: Sò uma observação, fazer md5(uniqid()) é um "crime". Está corrompendo a característica do uniqid gerando chance de colisões e matando a unicidade dele.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de um "nome aleatório" (o seu código não atinge este objetivo também!) poderia usar um "nome determinístico e único" para cada arquivo.

Para tais casos existem os *algoritmos de hashing*. Para isso poderia utilizar o [`hash_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php).

O objetivo é bem simples, faça o *hash*  do conteúdo que foi enviado, ele será o mesmo para o mesmo conteúdo e será diferente para cada foto diferente enviada <sup><sub>*(ignorando o [principio da casas dos pombos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_casa_dos_pombos), já que colisões são consideradas insignificantes em hashes seguras)*</sub></sup>.

---

```
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo(basename($_FILES["linkimg"]["name"]),PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$imagem = hash_file('sha384', $_FILES['linkimg']['tmp_name']) . '.' . $imageFileType;
$target_file = $target_dir . $imagem;
```

Não sei se o código irá atingir esse objetivo (não uso mais PHP e não tenho instalado para testar). A ideia é como descrito anteriormente. O novo nome da imagem será a hash (SHA-384) do próprio **conteúdo** enviado, não deve fazer a hash do nome da imagem. *A escolha do `SHA-384` é porque ele não é vulnerável ao length-extension attack.*

Sempre que enviar a **mesma foto** (o mesmo conteúdo) terá sempre o mesmo nome, assim saberá que ele já foi enviado.

Comment: Queria saber a razão do `-1`, se o código não funciona como deveria ou se ele não resolve o problema do OP ou se há alguma imprecisão na explicação contida resposta. (: